# Search XML file for nodes with specific attribute value in .NET 2

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-2.0

I found answers for searching XML nodes using LINQ, but I am limited to C# with .NET 2.

I want to open a single XML file (~50Kb, all simple text) and search for all `<Tool>` nodes with attribute `name` having a specific value.

It seems like `XmlDocument.SelectNodes()` might be what I'm looking for, but I don't know XPath. Is this the right way and if so what would code look like?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use XPath in XmlDocument.SelectNodes such as: `SelectNodes("//ElementName[@AttributeName='AttributeValue']")`

Xml Sample:

```
<root>
    <element name="value1" />
    <element name="value2" />
    <element name="value1" />
</root>
```

C# Sample:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
// Load Xml

XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//element[@name='value1']");
// nodes.Count == 2
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) you can find some additional XPath samples

Answer (score 4):

think you  could do something like that (well, rustic, but you've got the idea), using `GetElementsByTagName`

```
var myDocument = new XmlDocument();
myDocument.Load(<pathToYourFile>);
var nodes = myDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Tool");
var resultNodes = new List<XmlNode>();
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.Attributes != null && node.Attributes["name"] != null && node.Attributes["name"].Value == "asdf")
    resultNodes.Add(node);
}
```

Comment: @John Hmmm, well, you can use it in .Net2 under some conditions : see http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/01/23/use-c-3-features-from-c-2-and-net-2-0-code.aspx

Comment: this works great but the XPath answer is just more elegant for my purpose.

Comment: @John oh, well, no justification needed ;)