# Getting an XmlNode given one of its XmlAttributes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XmlNode like this:

```
XmlNode node = document.GetElementById("myid");
```

Given its attribute:

```
XmlAttribute a = node.Attributes("type");
```

Is there a way to obtain back the node?
Something like this:

```
XmlNode node = a.Node;
```

I tried `ParentNode`, but it doesn't seem to work (returning `null`).

Comment: How about using XPath?

Comment: @EZI I don't want all elements with the same attribute value, I want __that__ element. Is it possible?

Comment: @ProGM Yes, XPath can do that. I've included that in my answer.

Comment: @ProGM What should I understand from your comment. You don't know XPath or you are just pedantic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.ownerelement(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
XmlElement node = a.OwnerElement;
```

or using XPath:

```
XmlNode node = a.SelectSingleNode("..");
```

In terms of flexibility, the first approach requires the variable `a` to already be an `XmlAttribute` or requires you to cast it to one, but it gives you an `XmlElement` without requiring an explicit cast.

In contrast, `a` only has to be an `XmlNode` to use the second approach, but the return value on the method is also an `XmlNode`.

Answer (score 1):

This SO thread should answer your question
[Search XML file for nodes with specific attribute value in .NET 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501038/search-xml-file-for-nodes-with-specific-attribute-value-in-net-2).

XPath is also an option, because after you get all elements that match you can use Linq to get the specific node that you're interested in.