# How to search Node->Node->Attibute using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xmldocument

My XML looks like this. I want to get "NGSPkgTrackingId" 
I have to walk Node->Node->Attribute.
I need some help

```
<TrackingID>{06EB4234-8A65-4C28-AD45-DAC87B972437}</TrackingID>
<Documents>
    <Details Weight="1.7950" ZIP="04011" ZIPPlus4="3103" >
        <Identifier Qualifier="eVSBarcode" Value="4200401192458927004050120118829995" />
        <Identifier Qualifier="REFERENCENUM" Value="301113159600798" />
        <Identifier Qualifier="NGSPkgTrackingId" Value="00983482428">   
    </Details>
    <Details Weight="3.3450" ZIP="04011" CountryCode="US"  >
      < Identifier Qualifier="eVSBarcode" Value="4200401192612927004646230017808858" />
      <Identifier Qualifier="REFERENCENUM" Value="117913788" /> Default="true" />
    </Details>
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use `SelectSingleNode()` passing suitable XPath expression parameter to get specific part of XML through `XmlDocument`. What have you tried and what was the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search XML file for nodes with specific attribute value in .NET 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501038/search-xml-file-for-nodes-with-specific-attribute-value-in-net-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking up the [msdn documentation on XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx). As har07 pointed out, you can use *SelectSingleNode()*. Which you can reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx).

As for what the code could look like, assuming you just want to find the value associated with a given Identifier Qualifier, it could work like this:

```
    public static string FindValue(string qualifier, string xml)
    {
        var value = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xml);

        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNode identifier = root.SelectSingleNode(@"descendant::Details/Identifier [@Qualifier='" + qualifier +"']");

        value = identifier.Attributes["Value"].Value;

        return value;
    }
```

We should be doing null reference checks, so I'll add them in

```
    public static string FindValue(string qualifier, string xml)
    {
        var value = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xml);

        XmlNode identifier = null;
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        if (root != null)
            identifier = root.SelectSingleNode(@"descendant::Details/Identifier [@Qualifier='" + qualifier +"']");

        if (identifier?.Attributes != null) value = identifier.Attributes["Value"].Value;

        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Documents>
    <Details Weight="1.7950" ZIP="04011" ZIPPlus4="3103" >
        <Identifier Qualifier="eVSBarcode" Value="4200401192458927004050120118829995" />
        <Identifier Qualifier="REFERENCENUM" Value="301113159600798" />
        <Identifier Qualifier="NGSPkgTrackingId" Value="00983482428"/>   
    </Details>
    <Details Weight="3.3450" ZIP="04011" CountryCode="US">
      <Identifier Qualifier="eVSBarcode" Value="4200401192612927004646230017808858" />
      <Identifier Qualifier="REFERENCENUM" Value="117913788" /> Default="true" />
    </Details>
</Documents>
```

> Accessing  the value "NGSPkgTrackingId" should be pretty straightforward using the below code

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();   
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("C:/Users/.../documents.xml ");
            xmlDoc.Load(reader);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Documents").Item(0).ChildNodes;
            string val = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].LastChild.Attributes.Item(0).Value;
            Console.WriteLine(val);
```

> Alternatively, you can use selectNodes

```
        var node2 =xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(".//Details/Identifier");
        var ans1=  node2.Item(2).Attributes["Qualifier"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(ans1);
```

> Third Option

```
            var value= xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("descendant::Details").LastChild.Attributes["Qualifier"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Thank you all...  The NGSTrackingID might not be at the same place and I have iterate through all the "Details" node and then attributes of "Details" child's nodes.