# Need help selecting xml node by attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to select xml nodes by an attribute value.

I can navigate the nodes by drilling down through the children nodes. I can outright select any nodes by an means.

Here is the sample xml file i am using to test with.

```
<svg version="1.1" archibusversion="24.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="1284.03 1666.86 8172 3392">
    <g id="viewer">
        <g id="mirror" transform="scale(1, 1)" stroke-width="0.05%">
            <g id="background" fill="none"/>
            <g id="annotations" fill="none" />
            <g id="text" font-family="Arial" font-size="1.3" font-weight="normal" text-style="normal" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="alphabetical" fill="#000000" xml:space="preserve" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is my sample code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(@"test.svg");

    XmlNode root = document.DocumentElement;

    XmlNodeList nl = document.SelectNodes("//element[@id='background']");
}
```

I am expecting to be able to retrieve the node  from the svg file.  this node will have many children that I need to work with.

Comment: What namely you're trying to get from XML? For now, it's not clear...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search XML file for nodes with specific attribute value in .NET 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501038/search-xml-file-for-nodes-with-specific-attribute-value-in-net-2)

Comment: In your xpath expression, `element` should be the actual name of the element you want, or omitted if you want any element with that attribute.  Your XML doesn't contain any `<element>`

Comment: In the end I am looking to consolidate elements that are underneath the element <g id="background"/> It will have many Child nodes that are layers in the file. I need to re-name the layers, and consolidate the drawing elements  to  only a few nodes.

Comment: @Amy, I have tried to use ```XmlNodeList nl = document.SelectNodes("//g[@id='background']");``` as well, since the node is <g/> but that also results in an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method to do just that using `LINQ`.

```
public bool GetAllElementsByAttributeValue(XElement startingNode, Relationship findAmong, string attName, string attValue, out IEnumerable<XElement> matchingNodes, out string msg)
{
    bool ret = true;
    msg = "SUCCESS";
    matchingNodes = null;

    try
    {
        switch (findAmong)
        {
            case Relationship.Descendants:
                matchingNodes = from items in startingNode.Descendants()
                                where items.Attribute(attName) != null && items.Attribute(attName).Value == attValue
                                select items;
                break;

            case Relationship.Ancestors:
                matchingNodes = from items in startingNode.Ancestors()
                                where items.Attribute(attName) != null && items.Attribute(attName).Value == attValue
                                select items;
                break;

            case Relationship.Siblings:
                matchingNodes = from items in startingNode.Parent.Descendants()
                                where items.Attribute(attName) != null && items.Attribute(attName).Value == attValue
                                select items;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msg = ex.Message;
        ret = false;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

`Relationship` is an `enum` I defined to distinguish between Descendant, Ancestor, and Sibling elements.

```
public enum Relationship
{
    Ancestors = 0,
    Siblings = 1,
    Descendants = 2
}
```

**Usage:**

```
static void Main()
{
    var path = @"data.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
    GetAllElementsByAttributeValue(xdoc.Root, Relationship.Descendants, "id", "background", out IEnumerable<XElement> nodes, out string msg);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```